# How do I change the order of the product compared and viewed block in Magento?

Tags: xml, magento

I’m trying to move 'recently view products' block to below the 'compare products' block in the right sidebar. I’ve managed achieve this by the following inclusion in local.xml, however, the product viewed block appears twice now, with the original still sitting at the top. How do I code the xml to just send the top to the bottom, instead of duplicating as I have done?

```
<reference name="right"> 
    <!-- Mage_Reports -->
    <block type="reports/product_compared" name="right.reports.product.compared" template="reports/product_compared.phtml" after="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>product_compared</block_id></action>
    </block>
    <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" after="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>product_viewed</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `product_viewed` block is inserted in `app/design/frontend/yourinterface/yourtheme/layout/catalog.xml` and in `app/design/frontend/yourinterface/yourtheme/layout/reports.xml`. If you delete the corresponding tags in these files, the block should only appear once.
If these files are not included in your theme, just copy them into your theme from `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/` and edit them afterwards.

Happy coding :-)